# PyQt documentation offline

Tags: qt, pyqt, documentation

Does anyone know if an offline version of the latest PyQt4 and PyQt5 documentation is available somewhere on the Internet? I don't want to depend on whether I have a working Internet connection or not. I can of course grab it using `wget` or similar but I would prefer if I can do that the "normal" way (a PDF version would also be nice).

**Note:** Mny things are covered by the official Qt documentation (C++) however there are also things specific to Python. An example for such a treat is the fact that in C++ there are functions which have multiple overloaded versions while in Python such a thing is not possible. I find myself ever so often looking into the PyQt docs to see how this and that Qt thing looks like in Python.

Comment: "the fact that in C++ there are functions which have multiple overloaded versions while in Python such a thing is not possible" - that's wrong. You can dynamically check the arguments and dispatch to the right overload, which is exactly what PyQt is doing so you can use any C++ overload from Python.

Comment: Not so simple as you say it is. Please check the startDetached() documentation on QProcess in PyQt.

Comment: I'm guessing you mean that it returns `Tuple[bool, int]` instead of taking a `qint64 *pid` and returning `bool`? Yeah, there are a handful places where the signature differs as you can't pass a pointer in Python - that's unrelated to overloading though, as e.g. the `startDetached(str) -> bool` overload will work fine in Python as well ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PyQt source releases contain the documentation in `doc/html`.

You can also use the Python builtin `help()` on a PyQt object - often that way you'll get more relevant information (like the exact Python signatures) compared to the documentation.

Comment: Thanks, just looked into it and there it was. :)

Comment: I edited the answer to also talk about `help()`.

Comment: Yeah, `help()` also works however I find it much faster navigate through the HTML version of the docs. Still useful edit.

Answer (score -1):

Qt comes with a dedicated program, called *Qt Assistant*, that can be used to browse the documentation off-line. I use it regularly. It's C++ only obviously.

I don't know where it is installed on your system but it may very well be in the same directory as the *Qt Designer*.

Comment: The OP is asking about the **PyQt** documentation.

Comment: Yeap, PyQt is what I'm asking for. I use Qt C++ with Qt Creator on a daily basis so I'm familiar with the integrated documentation there. ;)

Comment: Oh yeah. I should read more carefully.